# Is it impossible to compute the difference between the maxBound and minBound of an Enum type?

Tags: haskell

Am I right to conclude that there's no way to compute `maxBound - minBound` in Haskell for an arbitrary `Enum` and `Bounded` type?  Or am I missing some trick/hack?  This is what I have, which clearly can't work:

```
difference :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => Int
difference = fromEnum maxBound - fromEnum minBound
```

Error:

```
Foo.hs:37:1:
    Ambiguous constraint `Enum a'
      At least one of the forall'd type variables mentioned by the constraint
      must be reachable from the type after the '=>'
    In the type signature for `difference': difference :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => Int

Foo.hs:37:1:
    Ambiguous constraint `Bounded a'
      At least one of the forall'd type variables mentioned by the constraint
      must be reachable from the type after the '=>'
   In the type signature for `difference': difference :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => Int
```

I understand why I'm getting that error—there's no actual term in there with type `a`, so it can't figure out what `a` is.  The question is whether there's a way to get around this.

Comment: I asked wrong the first time around. I've edited the question.

Comment: how would you *use* such a value as this?

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination I have an Enum/Bounded type, and wanted to construct a tree of all possible `fromEnum` values for that type. It's convenient to be able to have a recursive function like `mkTree lower upper` (which works however, it's not that hard) break the problem up into smaller ranges of ints. But to kick things off you need to be able to write `mkTree (fromEnum minBound) (fromEnum maxBound)` and get the bounds of the right type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `Proxy` to specify which type you want, and use `ScopedTypeVariables` to bring that type into scope in your function definition.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

data Proxy a = Proxy

difference :: forall a . (Enum a, Bounded a) => Proxy a -> Int
difference Proxy = fromEnum (maxBound :: a) - fromEnum (minBound :: a)

>>> difference (Proxy :: Proxy Bool)
1
```

Edit: Using Daniel's suggestion:

```
data Proxy a = Proxy

difference :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => Proxy a -> Int
difference p = fromEnum (max' p) - fromEnum (min' p) where
    max' :: (Bounded a) => Proxy a -> a
    max' Proxy = maxBound
    min' :: (Bounded a) => Proxy a -> a
    min' Proxy = minBound
```

Comment: This can also be done without scoped type variables, if you want to avoid extensions. `foo :: Bounded a => Proxy a -> (a,a); foo _ = (minBound, maxBound); difference p = let (min, max) = foo p in fromEnum max - fromEnum min`

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks.  I like your version better.

Comment: I must say I like the `Proxy` with the phantom type parameter better  than Dave's answer that uses `undefined`.

Answer (score 12):

```
difference :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> Int
difference x = fromEnum (maxBound `asTypeOf` x) 
             - fromEnum (minBound `asTypeOf` x)
```

Call it as e.g. `difference (undefined :: Char)`.

But note that this will overflow for some types (most notably `Int`), so instead use an `Integer` result:

```
difference :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> Integer
difference x = toEnum (fromEnum (maxBound `asTypeOf` x)) 
             - toEnum (fromEnum (minBound `asTypeOf` x))
```